# Building half a sphere, I get a hole at the tip. How do I set the triangles?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, geometry

I'm building a dome and it's going great, it's just that i don't know how to connect the very last vertices on top when setting up the triangles. The vertices go like this:

```
for (int i=0; i<scalex; ++i) {
            for (int j=0; j<scaley; ++j) {
                verticesSky[i*scaley+j].x=radius*Mathf.Cos(j*2*M_PI/scaley)*Mathf.Cos(i*M_PI/(2*scalex));
                verticesSky[i*scaley+j].y=radius*Mathf.Sin(i*M_PI/(2*scalex));
                verticesSky[i*scaley+j].z=radius*Mathf.Sin(j*2*M_PI/scaley)*Mathf.Cos(i*M_PI/(2*scalex));
            }
        }
```

And the triangle setup:

```
for (int i=0; i<scalex-1; ++i) {
            for (int j=0; j<scaley; ++j) {

                trianglesSky[ind++] = i*scaley+j;
                trianglesSky[ind++] = i*scaley+(j+1)%scaley;
                trianglesSky[ind++] = (i+1)*scaley+(j+1)%scaley;

                trianglesSky[ind++] = i*scaley+j;
                trianglesSky[ind++] = (i+1)*scaley+(j+1)%scaley;
                trianglesSky[ind++] = (i+1)*scaley+j;
            }
        }
```

Once again, the very top vertex does not connect with its neighbours, I get a hole at the tip.

Comment: Please use unity3d tag.

Comment: could you add a screenshot?

Answer (score 0):

The very top triangles were not showing up, i was getting a hole right at the top. i fixed it by manually adding a vertex there, in the middle, and connecting it with its neighbors. Thanks anyway, guys!